# Add a user to edit the layout of a site

Tags: admin, users

Currently, when I sign in I can edit the site - the layout, the number of pages, the theme, everything.

I want another user to also be able to do this. I don't care about what role they have or anything like that, I just want them to have all the abilities on the site.

When I add new users to the site they get "admin" privileges, but they don't get the little WordPress dashboard ability for the site.

How do i give some new user this ability?

Comment: If you are adding the user as administrator then they must be able to get same permissions. I just verified this by reproducing the scenario. I am not sure what is the registration process you are following. But if you are adding the user in a standard way from wordpress dasboard then make sure you change the role from subscriber to administrator while registration. If this doesn't solve your problem, pls share the steps you are using to create a user.

Answer (score 0):

We may need a little more information on the version of WordPress you are running, or at least the interface you are seeing that the new admin is not seeing.  Typically, when I troubleshoot WordPress installations and I have to add an administrator, I have full access just like an admin.  So, it shouldn't be any different for you. Make sure that the role of the user that you add is set to **Administrator**.

If my answer doesn't help, please provide us a little more information about the issue and we'd be glad to investigate it further.

Regards,
Arnel C.